# If and only if condition for a product space to be hausdorff.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, infinite-product

Is this true

$\forall i \in I \ X_i $ is hausdorff $\iff \prod_{i \in I}X_i $ is hausdorff.

I understand that $(\rightarrow )$ is true but don't know if $(\leftarrow)$ is true. If the other direction is true then is it true for both the box and product topology, if so how does one show this, if not true is there any counter example.(Where I is assumed to be a infinite index)

Comment: I don't understand, well I could consider the projection map if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, it’s true for both the ordinary product and the box product. In both cases each factor space $X_i$ is homeomorphic to a subset of the product. Specifically, let $X$ be the product, let $p\in X$ be arbitrary, and let $Y=\{x\in X:x_j=p_j\text{ for all }j\in I\setminus\{i\}\}$; then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X_i$.

Comment: Came across this a few years too late, but actually this is false! We need to also assume that each $X_i$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection map may not be good enough; the continuous image of a Hausdorff space is not necessarily Hausdorff.

Hint: You can find a copy of $X_n$ inside of the product.  For each $i\in I$ let $p_i\in X_i$. Let $n$ be given. Consider $$Y_n:=\left\{(x_i)\in \prod X_i:x_i=p_i\text{ for }i\neq n\right\}\;.$$

Comment: @Brian Freaky how we simultaneously chose $Y$ and $p$.

Comment: Oh right great thanks, just to confirm, so Yn is homeomorphic to Xn and Yn is hausdorff because it's a subset of Hausdorff space. Hence Xn is hausdorff.

Comment: @Topologyguy yes that's exactly right.  You just have to check that it is a homeomorphic